# Underwriters refusing to use TheWorkNumber

Tags: united-states, mortgage, loans, employment

Earlier this year, an underwriting department informed me they are no longer allowed to accept TheWorkNumber for employment verification purposes on any Fannie Mae Freddie Mac loans because of potential fraud issues. A second, unrelated broker is now telling me he can't use it as well.

If this is an official position, I can't find reference to it anywhere. Does this just depend on the lender I'm working with? Has anyone else come across this issue? I'd like nothing more than for companies to be forced to provide some other means. The worst part of applying for any loan is dealing with TheWorkNumber.

Comment: That'll be a policy decision of the individual insurance companies, although it may have become an accepted Best Practice.

Comment: My company, and may others deal with this by providing a employment verification service.  In my company's case they use a third party vendor which charges the requester for verification.  The more info they want, the more is charged.  And yes you have to authorize the information to be provided.

Comment: @PeteBelford Isn't that what TheWorkNumber is?

Comment: Maplemale, can we take it as given that your employer refuses to do any other employment verification than TheWorkNumber?

Comment: Honestly this confuses me quite a bit, based on a quick google search: Fannie Mae relatively recently (2010) contracted with TheWorkNumber to *be* their employment verification service.  Nothing about them suddenly stopping...

Comment: Yes, my company only uses TheWorkNumber. HR policy: No one is allowed to verify employment any other way. The previous lender just called our company's 1-800 number (I work for a large fortune 500) over and over again, until they got a CSR stupid enough to relay internal information out of the org chart to the lending company. This was American Financing in this case.

Comment: @Joe
Very interesting. I'm going to bring this up with my lender! They are a direct lender. But, they sell all of their loans and basically "have the same requirements as if it was a Fannie / Freddie loan." And I quote: "anytime we are dealing with run of the mill home loans which may be sold to Fannie / Freddie, we can't use TheWorkNumber..."

Maybe it is just their personal preference. Seems odd that i'm getting this twice in a row with two different lenders.

Comment: I don't work in the industry so I have no idea - just odd that the google search doesn't show anything if it's some sort of official policy.

Comment: On a side note, have you asked if they'll accept any other sort of employment verification - such as regular and recent pay stubs?  I used to (a long time ago) work for Borders, and many employees needed verification post-bankruptcy (after a time, TWN stopped verifying since Borders wasn't paying any more).  Paystubs usually sufficed (though for "past" income, since they obviously weren't current employees).

Comment: Apparently income verification is separate from salary. Both of my last two mortgage transactions required each separately. Doesn't make sense to me at all. But then I'm not actively attempting mortgage fraud, so maybe I just don't understand the reasons.